# Method for importing files into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

fileName = "JohnnyPiesData.csv"
pie_df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
```

This is the way my (remote) instructor says to load files. Be it, read_csv, read_exe,etc.
Why? Wouldn't it just be a a couple of lines simpler to eliminate fileName and make

```
pie_df = pd.read_csv("JohnnyPiesData.csv")
```

Comment: If the script gets longer it's sometimes easier to have any variables you might change (like a filename, or some #) defined fairly close to the top so if you were to revisit the script months later it would be obvious what to change instead of scanning through the entire code to find that one spot to change. But at that point, it would be clearer to write a method with arguments and a doc string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is perfectly fine, this is mostly a matter of habit here. Actually, using variables is not necessarily encouraged if you're not going to reuse them later. Here I would definitely go with the second option, but it doesn't really matter. Word of advice, do what your instructor likes for your assignments and whatever **you** like for your projects.